# How to get a simple hyperlink to work in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, hyperlink

When I run this and click on the link, I would expect a browser to open and it go to google, but **nothing** happens:

```
<Window x:Class="TestHyperlink2343.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>
            You and read this or 
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com">go to google</Hyperlink>
             etc.
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So then I replace the above code with the following and **still** nothing happens. However, surprisingly, if I **right click** on the link, it goes to google:

```
<Window x:Class="TestHyperlink2343.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>
            You and read this or 
            <Hyperlink MouseDown="Hyperlink_MouseDown">go to google</Hyperlink>
             etc.
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>

private void Hyperlink_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
}
```

**Why don't these examples work as expected and how can I get a simple hyperlink to work as users are accustomed to them working in web browsers (left click, open browser, go to site)?**

## Addendum

I solved this by creating my own hyperlink **without** the Hyperlink element like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="More info at wikipedia" 
  TextDecorations="Underline" 
  MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown_Wikipedia"/>

private void TextBlock_MouseDown_Wikipedia(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.wikipedia.com");
}
```

Strange that hyperlink doesn't work this easily.

Answer (score 5):

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.aspx) states:

> **Hyperlink** navigation can only occur, however, if either the direct or indirect parent of a **Hyperlink** is a navigation host, including [NavigationWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow.aspx), [Frame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.aspx), or any browser that can host XBAPs (which includes Internet Explorer 7, Microsoft Internet Explorer 6, and Firefox 2.0+). For more information, see the **Navigation Hosts** topic in [Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx).

Without seeing more of your code I don't know whether this applies in your case or not.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. I believe all you needed to do different was specify the left-mouse click specifically-

MouseLeftButtonDown

This has a lot of good info-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10667643/3692082