# Why IsMouseOver is recognized and MouseDown isn't (Wpf Style trigger)?

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles

Why IsMouseOver is recognized as a WPF style trigger and MouseDown isn't -given that both are valid UIElement properties as [seen here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx)-. First trigger works well but second one doesn't even compile.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush >
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="MouseDown" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="OpacityMask">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Don't know, but `MouseDown` isn't listed as a property at that link you provided.  `OnMouseDown()` is listed as a method called in response to an event, but not a property.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, I guess you are mistaking `MouseDown` event for property. There is no `IsMouseDown` property but there exist similar `IsPressed` property but only for classes inheriting `ButtonBase`. You should just use event in code-behind or write an attached property if you want to keep your code-behind clean.

This is how you do it. Create class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace Mrpyo
{
    public static class MouseDownHelper 
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsEnabled", 
        typeof(bool), typeof(MouseDownHelper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnNotifyPropertyChanged)));

        public static void SetIsEnabled(UIElement element, bool value)
        {
            element.SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
        }

        public static bool GetIsEnabled(UIElement element)
        {
            return (bool)element.GetValue(IsEnabledProperty);
        }

        private static void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = d as UIElement;
            if (element != null && e.NewValue != null)
            {
                if ((bool)e.NewValue)
                {
                    Register(element);
                }
                else
                {
                    UnRegister(element);
                }
            } 
        }

        private static void Register(UIElement element)
        {
            element.PreviewMouseDown += element_MouseDown;
            element.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += element_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            element.MouseLeave += element_MouseLeave;
            element.PreviewMouseUp += element_MouseUp;
        }

        private static void UnRegister(UIElement element)
        {
            element.PreviewMouseDown -= element_MouseDown;
            element.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown -= element_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            element.MouseLeave -= element_MouseLeave;
            element.PreviewMouseUp -= element_MouseUp;
        }

        private static void element_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = sender as UIElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                SetIsMouseDown(element, true);
            }
        }

        private static void element_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = sender as UIElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                SetIsMouseLeftButtonDown(element, true);
            }
        }

        private static void element_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = sender as UIElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                SetIsMouseDown(element, false);
                SetIsMouseLeftButtonDown(element, false);
            }
        }

        private static void element_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = sender as UIElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                SetIsMouseDown(element, false);
                SetIsMouseLeftButtonDown(element, false);
            }
        }

        internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsMouseDownPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("IsMouseDown",
        typeof(bool), typeof(MouseDownHelper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseDownProperty = IsMouseDownPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

        internal static void SetIsMouseDown(UIElement element, bool value)
        {
            element.SetValue(IsMouseDownPropertyKey, value);
        }

        public static bool GetIsMouseDown(UIElement element)
        {
            return (bool)element.GetValue(IsMouseDownProperty);
        }

        internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsMouseLeftButtonDownPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("IsMouseLeftButtonDown",
        typeof(bool), typeof(MouseDownHelper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMouseLeftButtonDownProperty = IsMouseLeftButtonDownPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

        internal static void SetIsMouseLeftButtonDown(UIElement element, bool value)
        {
            element.SetValue(IsMouseLeftButtonDownPropertyKey, value);
        }

        public static bool GetIsMouseLeftButtonDown(UIElement element)
        {
            return (bool)element.GetValue(IsMouseLeftButtonDownProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your style:

```
<Setter Property="local:MouseDownHelper.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="local:MouseDownHelper.IsMouseLeftButtonDown" Value="True">
        <!-- ... -->
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

And of course add namespace in your XAML file (look at the top):

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Mrpyo"
```

Comment: can you provide an example of what you're talking with "write an attached property"?

Comment: Thanks so much for this class. I had to use the PreviewMouseDown and  PreviewMouseUp events to get it to work, but after that it was awesome.

Comment: `IsPressed` is totally the right way to go if you're styling a button.

Comment: @mrpyo I'm using your solution (yes, even today :D ) but it doesn't work, no error, but does nothing. I'm using it on a rectangle that's a slider's thumb. What am I missing?

Comment: @agiro Have you tried using PreviewMouseDown and PreviewMouseUp like Robert Gowland recommended (I edited the answer)? Also remember that if you have harcoded values the trigger won't work: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/994aae5a-a852-4fc0-8eb7-9869dabf4ab7/trigger-on-ismouseover-on-rectangle-ellipse-or-other-shape?forum=wpf

Comment: @mrpyo Thanks for the heads up. I can get `IsMouseOver` to work, but not the click. How to use that `PreviewMouseDown` mentioned? looked for it but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @agiro I meant replacing `MouseDown` with `PreviewMouseDown` in `MouseDownHelper` etc. code (I've edited the answer to include that change, so now you just have to copy it).

Comment: e.Source will be the nested object that was clicked. To set the attached property on the object that the style is set on, cast sender as UIElement, instead of casting e.Source

Comment: You can use "IsMouseCaptured" instead

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MouseDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mousedown.aspx) in `Style.Triggers` but you have to use an [EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx) for that.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            ...
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

And remember that

> the action will not be undone once the condition that raised the event
>   is no longer true.

Answer (score 2):

You could use PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown when using Control.Triggers, replacing control with the control item the template is being used in:

```cs
<Grid>
  <Grid.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          ...
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```