# Change the Grid Background color with EventTrigger on MouseDown

Tags: c#, wpf, eventtrigger

I want Change the Grid Background in my UserContorl in XAML EventTrigger MouseDown
Below is mine code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OneCardApp.Ex.EntranceGuard.ControlManager.MapMonitoring.Map.MonitorDoor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded" FontSize="10" MouseDown="UserControl_MouseDown" MouseMove="UserControl_MouseMove" MouseUp="UserControl_MouseUp">
<Grid Height="60" Width="50" Name="content">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <GradientStop x:Name="Stop2" Color="Blue" Offset="1" x:Key="s"></GradientStop>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="blue"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="red"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="36"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Name="img_door" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Source="/OneCardApp.Ex;component/image/36/companyInfo.png"></Image>
    <Label Name="lbl_name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
</Grid>
```

I try to create add IsPressed trigger, but it don't have.
so,How do I do that.
Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a dupe of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667545

Comment: I want know how to change the grid background color when the mouse left button click the grid content with eventtrigger or tiggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

and choose color according to your requirement

```
     <Grid Height="60" Width="50" Name="content" Background="Transparent" Focusable="True">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <GradientStop x:Name="Stop2" Color="Blue" Offset="1" x:Key="s"></GradientStop>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="GotKeyboardFocus">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Green" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="36"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Name="img_door" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Source="/OneCardApp.Ex;component/image/36/companyInfo.png"></Image>
    <Label Name="lbl_name" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the code don't excute ,they could not resolve Background.Color property.

Comment: run this code separately it is working..your grid size is small.so maybe you didnt find out..try again

Comment: add this animation insted of previous if it not working   <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"  Value="Green" />
                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

Comment: i have change code..and previous code working too.as you said error in resolving background.color propety i just change the way of writing animation.plz notify me if it is working.thank you

Comment: Thanks you answer for me,and I try to change code again, writting "(Grid.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)",but is error ,"Background"   property not direct to path in "(0).(1)" DependencyObject. why would an error.

Comment: I dont what happend in your place but both code working fine in my Visuals studio.run this code separately from your project.may be your project dependancy createa a problem ..not sure.here your bug is not produce..sorry