# WPF Trigger not working because of other trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

I have a button that has two triggers.
One is on `IsMouseOver` and the other one on mouseClick.

If I comment the `IsMouseOver` one out the other one works perfectly fine but if I use both then the mouseClick one is ignored.

This are my Triggers:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="local:MouseDownHelper.IsMouseLeftButtonDown"
             Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.100"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="SendReportsButtonMainGrid"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                    To="{StaticResource ClickGray}" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
        <Trigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.100"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="SendReportsButtonMainGrid"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                    To="{StaticResource HoverGray}" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
             Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.400"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="SendReportsButtonMainGrid"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                    To="{StaticResource HoverGray}" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
        <Trigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.800"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="SendReportsButtonMainGrid"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                    To="{StaticResource HeaderGray}" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

The MouseDownHelper is from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667545/why-ismouseover-is-recognized-and-mousedown-isnt-wpf-style-trigger/10667643#10667643) as said it works wihout the other trigger.

**How can I have the OnHover effect and another one if the button is clicked?**

**EDIT:**
You can also use IsPressed that doesn't work either.

Comment: you don't show the MouseDownHelper code so maybe it's fine but did you try to trigger on the IsPressed property?

Comment: I tried that, it did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution using `StopStoryboard`.

I also added a second animation when clicking and I'm using onEnter and onLeave instead of onHover.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="local:MouseDownHelper.IsMouseLeftButtonDown"
             Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="StoryboardEnter"/>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.000"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="SendReportsButtonMainGrid"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                    To="{StaticResource HoverGray}" />
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.100"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="SendReportsButtonMainGrid"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                    To="{StaticResource ClickGray}" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
        <Trigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.100"
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="SendReportsButtonMainGrid"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                    To="{StaticResource HoverGray}" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
    </Trigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard Name="StoryboardEnter">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.200"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="SendReportsButtonMainGrid"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                To="{StaticResource HoverGray}" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation Duration="00:00:00.400"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="SendReportsButtonMainGrid"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                To="{StaticResource HeaderGray}" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```