# How do you get NavigateUri to work in a WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The mailto link doesn't work in this sample:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TextBlock>Please email
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="mailto:test@test.co.uk">test@test.cp.uk</Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
</Window>
```

It works if I change Window to UserControl.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963532/how-to-get-a-simple-hyperlink-to-work-in-xaml

Comment: Have a look on this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238694/example-using-hyperlink-in-wpf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Xaml : You need to add RequestNavigate

```
                    <TextBlock >
                        Please email <Hyperlink NavigateUri="mailto:test@test.co.uk"  RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">test@test.cp.uk</Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>
```

In code behind :

```
    private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: Worked a treat. Thanks for yor help.

Comment: I get exception "Program not found".

Comment: +1 and if you are getting an exception saying that the system cannot find the specified file, use `Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri) { UseShellExecute = true });` in place of the line above.